# Countability and maps

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Suppose A is an uncountable set and $B \subset A$ is countably infinite. Then $|A-B|=|A|$.
Is this true? I am unable to find a counter example. However, i'm unable to prove it either, any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes it is true. Removing a countably infinite subset from an uncountable set, leaves it still uncountable. For an example to help with intuition try $A=[0,1]$ and $B=\{1,1/2, 1/3,\dotsc\}$. It is a good exercise to try to construct a bijection $[0,1]\to [0,1]\setminus\{1/n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. But this is just an example, of course. To prove the fact in general, you can try contradiction, for instance.

Comment: @NapD.Lover but do uncountable sets always have the same size? I don't think so, for instance $\mathbb{R}$ and $P(\mathbb{R})$, there is no bijection between the two.

Comment: "but do uncountable sets always have the same size?"  No, but subtracting a countable (lesser cardinality) will not effect the cardinality or of a set of a high cardinality.  Removing a countable set from $P(\mathbb R)$ will not make the cardinality lower.

Comment: Hmm. No, good point. But I don't think removing a countable set is going to make $A \setminus B$ any bigger than $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$B=\{b_1, b_2, ...b_n,...\}$$

Let  $C = \{c_1, c_2, ...c_n,...\}$ a countable subset of $A-B$

Define a one-to-one corresponding  $f$ between $C$ and  $B\cup C$  as follows.

$$ c_1\to c_1, c_2\to b_1, c_3\to c_2 , c_4\to b_2,...$$

Now define a one-to -one correspondence $g(x) $ between $A-B$ and $A$ by $$g(x)=x,\text {for} x\in A- (B\cup C)$$ and  $$ g(x)=f(x) , \text {  for }  x\in   C$$

Thus $$|A|=|A-B|$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true. If at least one of $X$ and $Y$ are infinite, then $\vert X\cup Y\vert=\max(\vert X\vert,\vert Y\vert)$. Thus, $$\vert A\vert=\vert (A\setminus B)\cup B\vert=\max(\vert A\setminus B\vert,\vert B\vert)$$ Since $\vert A\vert\neq \vert B\vert$, this implies $\vert A\vert=\vert A\setminus B\vert$.

Comment: If somone were to ask, why do we know $|X\cup Y| > \max(|X|, |Y|)$ is impossible?

Comment: @fleablood WLOG assume $\vert X\vert\leq\vert Y\vert$ so $\vert X\cup Y\vert\leq\vert X\times\{0,1\}\vert$. Take a bijection $f:X\to\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is a cardinal. Define $g:X\times\{0,1\}\to X$ inductively by $g(x,0)=f^{-1}(\min\{\beta\in\alpha:f(\beta)\neq f(g(y,0))\text{ and }\beta\neq f(g(y,0))+1\text{ whenever }f(y)<f(x)\})$ and $g(x,1)=f^{-1}(f(g(x,0))+1)$. This is an explicit injection. More generally, $\vert A\times B\vert=\max(\vert A\vert,\vert B\vert)$ if at least of $A$ or $B$ is infinite.

Comment: That should say $\beta\neq f(g(y,0))$, not $f(\beta)\neq f(g(y,0))$.